# Create class member with link to itself

Tags: typescript

I had a class definition like so:

```
class Node {
    parent: Node | undefined = undefined;
    constructor(public name: string, parent?: Node) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

But that definition was cumbersome. When using `parent` as I needed to deal with `undefined` all the time. So I thought to change to:

```
class Node {
    constructor(public name: string, public parent: Node) {}
}
```

But that created the challenge to create a root object. I came up with this solution:

```
function createRootNode(): Node {
    const tmp = { name: "temorary name" };
    Object.assign(tmp, { parent: undefined });
    const root = new Node("/", tmp as Node);
    root.parent = root;
    return root;
}
```

It looks a bit like cheating. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't find the first implementation *all that* cumbersome.

But if you crave the concise, and I've understood the goal, why not

```
class Node {
    constructor(public name: string, public parent?: Node) {}
}
```

You don't need to declare optional `| undefined` or to initialize `= undefined` because `?:` does this for you, nor do you need any internal assignments owing to `public`.

[Test implementation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEByD2ATaBvAUNT1jwHYQBcAnAV2APiIAoAHEgIxAEthpcwBbAUwC5pCiTXAHMANNDqMWEsES64CAfj4JEASlQBfNNrQ58BaEXjxDAXjZcA7nCRUARMdMB9XEi721Abj15C0EFYLXGtbRAcQLgAzAmdgAAsmEERXd3txJwI1XwMjIMsbVQdBYXjYhKSUt0QPDJMsnP8iYXyQwrtHJlLY4SIwXEQK5NSa9LzsxvhIgDpEJmpM7P0IKa5Z%20apApb9V9YXgbfxduYWWtSA) (I renamed `Node` to `Nod` to quell warnings from LibDom):

```
class Nod {
    constructor(public name: string, public parent?: Nod) {}
}

const root = new Nod("root_node");
const lc = new Nod("left_child_node", root)
const rc = new Nod("right_child_node", root)
const rgc = new Nod("right_grandchild_node", rc)

console.dir(root)
console.dir(lc)
console.dir(rc)
console.dir(rgc)
```

Comment: Well, this still makes `parent` become `Nod | undefined`, and hence spreads castings or  `=== undefined` all over the code.

Comment: I wonder if this is an XY then. Usually, generic tree implementations don't reference parents at all, only children, and then you store a list of roots. Same thing with linked lists and heads. Why do you need to reference parents in yours?

Comment: It's kind of a file system, where .. refers to the parent. I guess another tree implementation is possible and circumvents the whole issue. But I was curious whether the way I created the root is really awkward.

Comment: @JohannesSchacht There isn't a way to make `parent` nullable without necessitating castings and null/undefined checks in your code. Or at least, not without doing some dynamic-type trickery on your code to get it to ignore the need for such things, in which case, why even bother using TypeScript at all if you are going to break it every time it seems inconvenient?